# Regex: to find a list of tags as end of line

Tags: c++, regex

I am a new to the field of regular expressions.

What I am trying to do here is to validate the data entered by user in a text box.

What I want to allow:
positive int value followed by `mm/cm/km/in/ft`

```
e.g. 1km, 12mm, 123in
```

are permitted.

I am using `std::regex` here.
But I am facing difficulty in validating the last tag which can be either one of `mm,cm,km,in,ft.`

I have written something like this:

```
std::regex_match( str, std::regex("[0-9]*[^a-zA-Z]*in$") );
// But this will suffice only for the int values followd by inches,
```

I want to know how i can write a regex which will return true if we have anything out of these `mm,cm,km,in,ft` at the end of value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use alternations `|` specifiy `OR` in regex

```
[0-9]+(mm|cm|km|in|ft)$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gK2fL7/1)

**OR**

Shortly

```
[0-9]+([mck]m|in|ft)$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gK2fL7/2)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::regex_match( str, std::regex("[0-9]\*[^a-zA-Z]\*(mm|cm|km|in|ft)$") );
```